# Сравнение множества значений

Tags: c++, c

Как коротко сравнить много значений на равенство? Надо такое поведение:

```
type value_1, value_2, value_3, ...
if (value_1 == value_2 && value_2 == value_3 && value_3 == ...)
```

Comment: [С++] и [C]? Никак по-другому не сравнить. Только так как у вас написано.

Answer (score 4):

Если они просто так записаны, как отдельные переменные - толку особого не будет. Если же это, скажем, элементы в контейнере - то можно воспользоваться алгоритмом типа `all_of` - например, пусть у вас `vector<int> v` - то что-то типа (не компилирую, просто набросок)

```
if (all_of(v.begin(),v.end(),[&v](auto x){ return x == v[0]; }))
```

Ну, словом, где-то так.

Answer (score 1):

Развивая ответ @Harry, можно предложить вариант для `vector<int> v` -

```
if(count(v.begin(),v.end(),v[0])==v.size()) {}
```

Comment: это менее оптимально. Мы пройдём скорее всего весь массив а не 2-3 элемента например.

Comment: @pavel Кстати, все это - что у меня, что тут - в принципе работает только для более-менее простых случаев. А что будет, если оператор && переопределен? :) Тогда теоретически должны быть вычислены все операторы ==, без всяких сокращенных вычислений. Ха, задачка теоретически сложнее, чем кажется :)